Who were the ancient gods in Tamilnadu?
Without considering mythology, according to real history, are Shiva and Vishnu pre-vedic Gods? In historical opinion who came first? And who were the ancient gods in Tamilnadu?

Vishnu is mentioned as God of mullai nilam (mountainous region) while Indra and Varuna are mentioned as Gods of cropland region and seashore region respectively in the oldest available Tamil literature Tolkappiyam. A festival called Indra vizha (festival of Indra) was celebrated as per sangam literature. There is no such thing called pre or post vedic here all the Vedic elements are already known to Tamil people or at least composers of Tamil Sangam literature

This question belongs in any history space and not here imo.

I) Your first question Without considering mythology, according to real history, are Shiva and Vishnu pre-vedic Gods?
There is no such concept of pre-vedic Gods. Gods belong to Vedic only.
II) Your second question In historical opinion who came first?
To know the answer philosophically, please refer my answer in the post: Who is greater Shiva or Visnu? or are they all equal?
In both Pre-Sangam and post-Sangam periods, Shiva and Vishnu have been worshiped equally everywhere. But it is hard to answer who came first because of the lack of evidence historically in southern India. Vedas praises vedic Gods and Purnas glorifies Gods not covered by Vedas. Shaiva religion spread over and dominated Vaisnava religion during Chozha period (சோழர் காலம்). Despite Chozha being staunch supporter of Shaiva, they were never antagonist to Vaisnavam. Equally the kings allotted grants equally to Vaisnava temples. This Chozha period can be divided as (1) Pre-Sangam (2) Sangam (3) Medieval and (4) Later .

சங்க காலத்திற்கு முற்பட்ட சோழர்கள்,  சங்ககாலச் சோழர்கள்,  இடைக்காலச்
சோழர்கள்,  பிற்காலச் சோழர்கள்

III) Your third and final question And who were the ancient gods in Tamilnadu?
Ancient Gods of Tamilnadu narrated in old Tamil literature, mostly the Sangam period (600 BCE–300 CE) in literary form, was characterized by the coexistence of religions which are Shaivism and Vaishnavism, later joined by Buddhism and Jainism.
Ancient Tamil grammatical works such as the Tholkāppiyam(தொல்காப்பியம்) and poetic works like the Pathuppāṭṭu(பத்துப்பாட்டு/Ten Idylls), and Eṭṭuttokai(எட்டுத்தொகை/the Eight Anthologies) sheds light on early religion of ancient Tamil people. Thirumāl (திருமால்/aka Perumāl/பெருமாள்) was glorified in almost all Sangam literature and was the only god who has the status of Paramporul(பரம்பொருள்/The Absolute). Thirumāl (aka Vishnu/விஷ்ணு) was the Supreme God for the Tamilians in Sangam age. Skanda (கந்தன்/aka Murugan/முருகன்) was considered young and a personal god of the Tamils. Murugan was glorified as, the red god seated on the blue peacock, who is ever young and resplendent. Tolkāppiyam mentions that each of these thinai(திணை/நிலத்திணை) had an associated deity(தெய்வம்):

மாயோன் மேய காடுறை யுலகமும்     
சேயோன் மேய மைவரை உலகமும்
வேந்தன் மேய தீம்புனல் உலகமும்   
வருணன் மேய பெருமணல் உலகமும்   
முல்லை குறிஞ்சி மருதம் நெய்தலெனச்  
சொல்லிய முறையாற் சொல்லவும் படுமே

Māyon(மாயோன்/திருமால்) in Mullai(முல்லை) — the Forest associated lands,
Seyyon(சேயோன்/முருகன்) in Kurinji(குறிஞ்சி) — Mountain associated lands, 
Ventan/Senon(வேந்தன்/சேணோன்) in Marutham(மருதம்) — lands associated with plains, 
Varunan/Kadalon(வருணன்/கடலோன்) in Neithal(நெய்தல்) — Coasts associated with sea.


Beware-1: Kotravai(கொற்றவை) in Pālai(பாலை) — the deserts.
Beware-2: Indra is associated with Vendhan(வேந்தன்) in தொல்காப்பியம்(Tholkappiyam).
.
Since Pre-Sangam and Post-Sangam periods, Shiava worship has been in Vogue.
During Chera, Chozha, Pandiya and Pallava periods plenty of temples came up for  Shiva worship. Many a times, the God being referred in poetic form. For example, instead of Shiva, He was mentioned due to his exploits such as burning of the 3 cities (...திரிபுரம் தீ மடுத்து...). He is mentioned as முக்கண் செல்வர் (Mukkan Selvar/Reference to Three eyes), ஈர்ஞ்சடை அந்தணன்(Eernchjadai Andhanan/Referring to Ganga in his mated hair), sometimes along with consort Uma(உமை). Sometimes, it is very unclear as to which god is mentioned. Some cite "...புல்லிலை யெருக்க மாயினு முடையவை கடவுள்..." as implying worship of Pillaiyār(Ganapati), but it need not be the case.
Vedic nature worship too was prevailed such as worshipping Trees (கடவுள் மரத்த முள் மிடை...), worshipping Mountain (வரை அர மகளிர் இருக்கை...), the great sea god (பெருங்கடல் தெய்வம்...), which may or may not refer to Varunan. நிலமகள்(Nilamagal) as the personification of the earth, the earth goddess can also be taken as an example. Rivers such as Kaveri (சிறக்க நின் ஆயுள் மிக்கு வரும் இன்னீர்க் காவிரி...) and Vaigai (காண் தீரமும் வையையும்) are mentioned and worshiped as they were the lifelines of land and it's people.
Nadukkal worship (நடுகல்/Hero stone) has been mentioned in both அகநானூறு(Agananooru)(பீலி சூட்டிய பிறங்கு நிலை நடுகல் வேல் ஊன்று பலகை..) and புறநானூறு (Purananooru)(நடுகல் கைதொழுது...) which is meant for fallen warriors in battles.
Sakra(शक्र/சக்ர) is a Sanskrit word meaning ""mighty"" or "powerful," and is used as an epithet of Indra in hymn 5.34 of the Rigveda. Indra is praised as the highest god in 250 hymns of the Rigveda. Ainkurunooru(ஐங்குறுநூறு) and also later in the Silapadhikaaram(சிலப்பதிகாரம்), Indra was widely worshipped in Tamil Nadu, where a big festival called Indra Vizha(இந்திர விழா/Festival of Indra) was celebrated in His honor by Choza Kings in Pūmpukar. Agricultural communities worship him to bring timely rains. Devotion to him brings human prosperity and happiness.
Yaman (யமன்/यम) was also revered and worshiped in many names such as கூற்றம்.
Worship of Vārāhī(வாராகி/वाराही) in order to win battles was in Vogue. The following are the worship mentioned in various Tamil works:

Kannagi(கண்ணகி) is mentioned as a goddess(கடவுள் பத்தினிக் கற்கோள்
வேண்டி...) even before Silapadhikaaram(சிலப்பதிகாரம்) in
Padhittrupathu(பதிற்றுப்பத்து).
Jain and Buddhist monasteries are described in
Maduraikānji (மதுரைக்காஞ்சி) according to the commentary of
Nachinārkiniyar.
The சிலப்பதிகாரம்(Silapadhikaaram) is a treasure trove of
information. Jainism, Buddhism , Vedic gods, gods such as
Saraswathi, Forest gods, deities such as சாத்தன்(Chaathan) from whom
Ayyanaar worship is descended are also found.
The Manimegalai(மணிமேகலை) and Kundalakesi(குண்டலகேசி) are said to be
Buddhist epics whereas the Jeevagachinthamani(சீவகசிந்தாமணி) and
Valaiyaapathi(வளையாபதி) are Jain epics.
The Pathinenkeelkanakku (பதினெண்கீழ்க்கணக்கு) is compilation of 18
texts with varying religious philosophies and the Bhakthi
literature, the 12 Thirumurai(பன்னிரு திருமுறைகள்) and Divya Prabhandham (திவ்யப்பிரபந்தம்) are Shaivite and Vainavite works respectively.
Mariamman (மாரியம்மன்/Goddess for rains), Natarajar (நடராஜர்/Dancing
form of Shiva) and Meenakshi (மீனாட்சி/Consort of Shiva) have been
worshiped fervently.
Bhairava(பைரவர்) is known as Vairavar(வைரவர்) in Tamil where he is often presented as a Grama Devata(கிராம தேவதை/folk deity) who safeguards the devotee on all eight directions. In Chola times Bhairava is referred as Bikshādanar(பிச்சாடனர்), a mendicant, and the image can be found in most Chola temples.
Most popular village deities are Sudalai Mādan (சுடலை மாடன்),
Madurai Veeran(மதுரை வீரன்), Karuppasāmy(கருப்பசாமி) ,
Mādasāmy(மாடசாமி), Sorimuthu Ayyanār(சொரிமுத்து அய்யனார்),
Muneeshwaran(முனீஸ்வரர்), and  Muniappasamy(முனியப்பசாமி).

There are few more village deities(கிராம தெய்வங்கள்) unaccounted and so the list is still longer.
Good Luck!
